# Error in running Makefile (in C) when creating a Linux Module

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have a code below and I need to compile it. However, I can not run the Makefile on my computer

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

int
simple_init(void)
{
  printk("Loading module\n");
  return 0;
}

void
simple_exit(void)
{
  printk("Removing module\n");
}

module_init(simple_init);
module_exit(simple_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple Module");
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m := simple.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

The problem is that: When I type Make in the terminal the following error occurs:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-75-generic/build 
SUBDIRS=/home/caiquefortunato/Área de Trabalho/kernel modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:148: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:693: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-
protector-strong not supported by compiler
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'de'.  Pare.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic'
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

What do I have to do to make it work? Do I need to install something?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `make` may mess things up when you have spaces in your folder paths. Try copying the build folder to a path with no spaces and run `make` again.

Comment: Resolved. Thank you so much. =D

Answer (score 2):

There are a few causes of the `CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support` error.

1) spaces in the compilation directory <== this is is you

2) `binutils` not installed

3) attempting to compile root-owned kernel source directory with unprivileged user